# Nivo Slideshow not working in IE9 - error 80020101

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, nivo-slider

My nivo slideshow works great on all browsers I have tested, but does not load at all in ie9. The dev console is giving me an 'error 80020101'.

No fix I have found so far has helped. I am using jquery-1.7.2.min.js as well as jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js(for the ui tabs, etc). The slideshow is called to the page through ajax.

Here is my jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect: 'slideInLeft',
directionNavHide: true,
animSpeed: 500, 
startSlide: 0,
controlNav: false,
pauseTime: 3000
});
});
```

and my html(which is from the php file):

```
<div class=\"slider-wrapper theme-default\">
<div class=\"ribbon\"></div>
<div id=\"slider\" class=\"nivoSlider\">
<img src=\"../adminConsole/images/gallery/slideshow.jpg\" alt=\"\" />
<img src=\"../adminConsole/images/gallery/ecco swim 1.jpg\" alt=\"\"  />
<img src=\"../adminConsole/images/gallery/ecco swim 2.jpg\" alt=\"\" />
<img src=\"../adminConsole/images/gallery/beach1.jpg\" alt=\"\"  />
</div>
</div>
```

The css is the basic default css (niv-slider.css) with the only addition being set height and width.

There are quite a few ridiculous widgets going on on this page(clocks (yes two), jquery calendar and a text scroll box) and this issue causes the subsequent widgets to not work. Could that be the problem? It all works fine together in other browsers. Perhaps a non-ajax solution would fix this - the error number is ajax related? Any help would be greatly appreciated.This job is killing me!

**EDIT:** Upon further inspection, this is definitely a problem with the ajax. Currently, all tabs make an ajax call to their respective pages, which display. EI9 does not like this at all. It works fine when used straight. 
However, I don't really want to have this page as straight html. Any ideas on how to make this thing display after an ajax call? All that displays is a forever loading image.

Comment: Is your page available online someplace for us to troubleshoot as well?

Comment: Have you looked at the console for errors in IE9? (Press F12.)

Comment: I have looked ta the errors. I got error 80020101. an ajax error. Apparently there is some kind of array issue in jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js. I have narrowed this down to an error IE is having during or after the ajax call is made. It seems to work perfectly if it is just called straight on the page.

Comment: you can visit academy.ututorost.com to view it. Its in development. The images are all pulled from a database (will be). There is a whole CMS console as well which drives all content. Also the page in question is called from php, so not much to see there on the browser side. I put the display code in my post. The images are not sliding right now, but that's just because the image links are incorrect. They slide fine on my local machine. That's not the issue.